# ifelse statement in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I am trying to create a calculated column using the code below. Lookup function works find until I added the IF statement above it. What I need is to fix the outcome to 1 when df[col] = "B0" or df[col] = "B1" otherwise outcome should give the lookup function result. how to get around with this ? many thanks in advance.

```
_FY23_AOP_Rate = 
 IF('df'[col] = "B0" || 'df'[col] = "B1", 
    1, 
    LOOKUPVALUE(
                    dimFX[FY23 AOP], 
                    dimFX[Currency Code], 'df'[Currency])
  
)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just missing an enclosing quote after B1?

```
IF('df'[col] = "B0" || 'df'[col] = "B1", 
    1, 
    LOOKUPVALUE(
                    dimFX[FY23 AOP], 
                    dimFX[Currency Code], 'df'[Currency])
  
)
```

Comment: my mistake which i did it here.

Comment: did work well after i changed the format of the columns. thank you very much.